# _react.default.useContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am using material ui stepper.
- I used from there site but its broken
- so I debugged and gave console inside VerticalLinearStepper method.
- its printting a method at this line   console.log("useStyles----->", useStyles);
- but I am facing an error _react.default.useContext is not a function
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/v3o3zmxk90

```
function VerticalLinearStepper() {
  console.log("useStyles----->", useStyles);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  function handleNext() {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
  }

  function handleBack() {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep - 1);
  }

  function handleReset() {
    setActiveStep(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@material-ui/styles has a peer dependency on react >= 16.7.0-alpha.0 and react-dom >= 16.7.0-alpha.0
Update your react and react-dom dependencies to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
},
```

Comment: "material-ui is deprecated use @material-ui/core instead" only to find out later that component examples for @material-ui/core include @material-ui/styles which depends on unstable version of react :(

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see, you are using a version of React that does not yet have support for hooks (`useXXX`)

It sometimes confuses me too, but `latest` as a version in your `package.json` actually means "Latest stable version".
To use a version that supports hooks, you can use the version `next` for `react` as well as `react-dom` :)